# DC Powered Microcontroller Damaged by Simultaneous Two Power Sources?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a Nordic microcontroller PCB that seems to have a random death syndrome which we think is due to a bad layout or some other design issue.

We were running some tests on the unit and accidentally supplied nominal 3.7V from a LiPo cell plus a nominal 3.7V from a USB powered converter.  The unit was fine for 1 day, and then the 2nd day it would not start again.

This seems like our random death syndrome, BUT -- we accidentally did apply two power sources, and I'm wondering if that could be a factor?

Is it possible that simultaneously DC voltages from the LiPo Cell plus the USB powered converter could damage a microcontroller?  Both sources were nominally the correct voltage but just applied accidentally at the same time.

Say perhaps the voltages are a little different at one given time?

Comment: Please provide a circuit showing how these two sources combine. Is there a charging controller in there somewhere? Is it just two parallel connectors? Have you traced out power to the MCU? Do you have a good ground return?

Comment: Which microcontroller? Is it a ready-made module, which module? How were all the power sources, USB and two batteries connected?

Comment: Also, what is the abs max voltage of that microcontroller PCB?